# How to debug seemingly random crashes of AucTeX?

Tags: auctex, crash

My Emacs crashes seemingly randomly. Is there a way to view the *Messages* buffer after it crashed? Or is there another standard way of approaching this problem? I'd like to see an error message so that I can start pinpointing the source of the crash.

I run Arch Linux with Emacs 25.1.1 and AucTeX 11.89-3

Answer (score 1):

For hard crashes (segfaults, aborts), you'll need to use `gdb`, see `etc/DEBUG`.

---

> I run Arch Linux with Emacs 25.1.1

It's probably Emacs bug#24821/24358, see https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=24821#8

> Does it help to apply the following patches?
>
> ```
> http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/patch/?id=9afea93ed536fb9110ac62b413604cf4c4302199
> http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/patch/?id=71ca4f6a43bad06192cbc4bb8c7a2d69c179b7b0
> http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/patch/?id=1047496722a58ef5b736dae64d32adeb58c5055c
> http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/patch/?id=96ac0c3ebce825e60595794f99e703ec8302e240
> http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/patch/?id=43986d16fb6ad78a627250e14570ea70bdb1f23a
> ```
>
> Alternatively, try configuring with `REL_ALLOC=no`.